# Autocomplete not working on dynamically created input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one input in the HTML when the page loads, while others are created dynamically through the JS code.

The autocomplete function works perfectly on only the first input, but not on the dynamically created ones. Why is this?

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="example" name="example[]" placeholder="Example" class="exampleInput" required/></td>
    <td><textarea name="ex[]" cols="8" rows="2" placeholder="Example" class="exampleTxtArea" required/></textarea></td>
    <td><button type="button" name="addElement" id="addElement" class="btnAddElement">+</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#addElement').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" 
       autocomplete="off" id="example" name="example[]" 
       placeholder="Example" class="exampleInput" required/></td>
       <td><textarea name="ex[]" cols="8" rows="2" 
       placeholder="Example" class="exampleTxtArea" 
       required/></textarea></td>  
       <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" 
       class="btn_removeRow">-</button></td></tr>');
    });

    $('#example' + i + '').autocomplete({
      source: 'input_search.php',
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_removeRow', function() {
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is because you only bind the `autocomplete()` when the page loads. It doesn't automatically apply itself to the new content you `append()`. You need to do this manually.

In addition, there's some other changes you should make to improve the quality of the code. Firstly, avoid putting HTML in JS. You can use a `template` for this instead.

In addition, never put `id` attributes in content which can be dynamically repeated. This is because `id` *have* to be unique in the DOM, and repeating the same elements will mean your HTML is invalid.

Similarly, don't use incremental `id` attributes which you create at runtime. It makes the code more complex than it needs to be and normally creates unnecessary global variables which should also be avoided. Use common `class` attributes to group elements by behaviour, and use DOM traversal in your JS logic to relate the elements within the event handlers.

With those improvements in mind, your code would look something like this:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="example[]" placeholder="Example" class="exampleInput" required /></td>
    <td><textarea name="ex[]" cols="8" rows="2" placeholder="Example" class="exampleTxtArea" required></textarea></td>
    <td><button type="button" name="addElement" id="addElement" class="btnAddElement">+</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<template id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="example" name="example[]" placeholder="Example" class="exampleInput" required /></td>
    <td><textarea name="ex[]" cols="8" rows="2" placeholder="Example" class="exampleTxtArea" required></textarea></td>  
    <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn_removeRow">-</button></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let rowTemplate = $('#row-template').html();

  $('#addElement').on('click', () => {
    let $content = $(rowTemplate).appendTo('#dynamic_field');
    $content.find('.exampleInput').autocomplete({
      source: 'input_search.php'
    });
  });

  $('.exampleInput').autocomplete({
    source: 'input_search.php'
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_removeRow', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory. Now, the autocomplete function works corretly (father and child, both). Instead, i can't remove dynamically created input-text (child) with your function: 
                                                                                                                $(document).on('click', '.btn_removeRow', e => {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, change `this` to `e.target` on that line. I updated the answer to give you the full example.